# InvalidCastException InvalidCastException while passing decimal array as parameter to stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core

I am trying to execute SP using OracleCommand using .NET Core 8, with below SP definition

```
PROCEDURE SPName(
    ID IN Int,
    BID IN Varchar2,
    Secroleid IN Decimal,
    Site IN Varchar2
  ) AS
```

My C# code to call procedure looks like below

```
public async Task<ProductUserRolesReplyItem> SaveProductUserRolesMultiplePcsNew(decimal pcid, List<ProductUserRoleSaveItem> productUserRoles)
{

    
    var query = string.Empty;
    ProductUserRolesReplyItem? productUserRolesReplyItem = null;
    var connectionstring = _appDBContext.GetConn();
    try
    {
        using (var conn = connectionstring)
        {


            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand
            {

                Connection = conn,
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                CommandText = "SPName",
                BindByName = true
            };



                foreach (ProductUserRoleSaveItem pURole in productUserRoles)
                {

                    var numRecs = pURole.ProductUserRoles.Count();
                    var ids = new string[numRecs];
              var roleids = new Decimal[numRecs];
                var sites = new string[numRecs];
                    var i = 0;

                    foreach (var productUserRole in pURole.ProductUserRoles)
                    {
                        idsids[i] = productUserRole.Idsid;
                   ids[i] = productUserRole.Role.Security_Role_Id;
                        sites[i++] = productUserRole.Site;
                   

                }
                
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ID", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = pcid;
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("BID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = ids;
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Secroleid", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = roleids.ToArray();
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Site", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = sites;
                if (numRecs > 0)
                    {

                    command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().Wait();
                    command.Transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new ProductUserRolesReplyItem
        {
            IsSuccess = false,
            Message = System.String.Format("Error encountered while saving product user roles: {0}", ex.Message)
        };
    }
    return new ProductUserRolesReplyItem { IsSuccess = true };

}
```

When I try to call the SP in  command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().Wait(); I get below error:
**InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'**

Unable to understand how do I correct this error?

Comment: Looking at https://blogs.oracle.com/connect/post/put-your-arrays-in-a-bind you appear to be missing `command.ArrayBindCount = numRecs;`. Also, have you tried getting it working for a single record before you tried using a bulk insert on multiple records?

Comment: Does the issue come from `command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Secroleid", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = roleids.ToArray();`, try to use a fixed value, and tell us the test result.

Comment: @MT0, Even single record does not work.

Comment: I modified the code as below  
int[] roleid = { 4 }; 
 command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("In_Security_Role_ID", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = roleid;
Now I get  InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Array'.

Comment: What did you expect if you pass an array to something that expects an `int`. Why not use `int roleid = 4;`?

Comment: Side note: If you want to use `async` then do `await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();` otherwise just do `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`. Do NOT use `.Wait()`

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, identifiers are case-sensitive. However, Oracle will appear to be case-insensitive when you use unquoted identifiers because it will implicitly convert lower- and mixed-case unquoted identifiers to upper-case.

Therefore:

```sql
PROCEDURE SPName(
  ID        IN Int,
  BID       IN Varchar2,
  Secroleid IN Decimal,
  Site      IN Varchar2
) AS
```

is the equivalent of:

```sql
PROCEDURE SPNAME(
  ID        IN Int,
  BID       IN Varchar2,
  SECROLEID IN Decimal,
  SITE      IN Varchar2
) AS
```

So your code may need to use upper-case identifiers and for a single value:

```c#
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand
{
  Connection = conn,
  CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
  CommandText = "SPNAME",
  BindByName = true
};

command.Parameters.Add(
  new OracleParameter("ID", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input)
).Value = pcid;
command.Parameters.Add(
  new OracleParameter("BID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)
).Value = productUserRoles[0].ProductUserRoles[0].Idsid;
command.Parameters.Add(
  new OracleParameter("SECROLEID", OracleDbType.Decimal,  ParameterDirection.Input)
).Value = productUserRoles[0].ProductUserRoles[0].Role.Security_Role_Id;
command.Parameters.Add(
  new OracleParameter("SITE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)
).Value = productUserRoles[0].ProductUserRoles[0].Site;

command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().Wait();
command.Transaction.Commit();
```

*Note: Untested but it should give you the general idea of how to simplify the problem and try to get a minimal single-record example working.*

Once you get a single-record insert working then you can modify it to use a bulk insert and pass multiple records - an example of which you can see [in this blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/connect/post/put-your-arrays-in-a-bind) - but you would need to transform all your individual scalar values into arrays of values for each parameter (even the static one for `pcid` would need to be an array) so that you have one array entry for every record and add `command.ArrayBindCount = lengthOfTheArrays;`.